# Any way to find out the classname that the td been clicked on .on('click' 'tr' function ()?

Tags: jquery

Just wondering, will it be possible for me to find out the the classname of the td that has been clicked when I'm using .on('click' 'tr' function () ?

following is the code that I having:

```
    <table id="testing">
      <tr id="2"> 
           <td class="test1"></td>
          <td class="test2"></td>
          <td class="test3"></td>
          <td class="test4"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

JQuery:

```
    $('#testing).on('click', 'tr.2', function () {

 });
```

Anyway that I can find out the class name (test1) when I click on the 1st td?

Comment: I'm noticing that in you're event delegation you're writing `tr.2`. I believe it should be `tr#2` given that it's an `id` attribute you seem to wanting to target. Note, however, that this doesn't address the original question. It's only a side note to address an error in your jQuery.

Comment: Why not bind to the cell?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle clicks on table cells then why not hook them up...?
But make sure your selectors are well written without any typos because in your question `tr.2` will not select anything since there are no table rows that has a "2" class. There's also a unclosed single-quotation literal/string in your jquery

```js
$('#testing').on('click', 'tr td', function () {
        console.log($(this).attr("class"));
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="testing">
      <tr id="2"> 
           <td class="test1">Test 1</td>
          <td class="test2">Test 2</td>
          <td class="test3">Test 3</td>
          <td class="test4">Test 4</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the snippet I've included, I added text within the opening/closing tags of the `td` elements. (Why? Because you need something visible to click on in order for you to verify your jQuery code is working). Aside from that, I haven't modified your original HTML.

To explain my jQuery code, I'll start off by noting that, like you, I'm delegating the `click` event(s). However, unlike you I'm targeting the `td` elements nested within the `table` element (via the `$('#testing')` selector) rather than `tr.2`, as you used.

Within the callback (anonymous) function I'm passing to jQuery's `$.on()` method, I'm using the `context` (*i.e.*, JavaScript's `this` keyword, or jQuery's equivalent, `$(this)`) to capture that particular `td` upon which the user clicks. We can chain the jQuery `.attr()` method to this selector, passing in the string `class` to retrieve the desired class name(s). For simplicity, I'm holding that value in state as the `$tableCellClass` variable (using ES6's `let` declaration -- which, for these purposes, can be thought of as just `var`). Logging that to the `console` should show you what you're looking for.

Hope this helps!

```js
$('#testing').on('click', 'td', function(evt) {
  let $tableCellClass = $(this).attr('class');
  console.log(`Cell Class(es):\t${$tableCellClass}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="testing">
  <tr id="2"> 
    <td class="test1">Test 1</td>
    <td class="test2">Test 2</td>
    <td class="test3">Test 3</td>
    <td class="test4">Test 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When clicking on element the event object contains `target` property.

```
$('#testing').on('click', 'tr#2', function (e) {
   // use closest() in case click on element inside `td`
   var $cellClicked = $(e.target).closest('td')
   if($cellClicked.index() === 0){
      console.log('clicked on first , class =  ',   $cellClicked.attr('class'))
   }else{
      console.log('Not first cell');
   }

});
```

Probably be simpler to listen to events on `td` instead of `tr`